# If each eigenvalueof $A$ is either $+1$ or $-1$ $ \Rightarrow$ $A$ is similar to ${A^{ - 1}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ is nonsingular and each eigenvalue of $A$ is either $+1$ or $-1$.Why $A$ is similar to ${A^{ - 1}}$?

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted so far? Or any thoughts?

Comment: Hint:  We have two facts.  (1) There exists a basis consisting of generalized eigenvectors of $A.$      (2)  There is a natural correspondence (in the special cases where $\lambda=\pm 1$) and the generalized eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^{-1}.$

Comment: Well, you could put $A$ into Jordan normal form $J$, then compute the inverse of $J$ by blocks, which isn't that hard to do by hand, and check.  This is just a explicit form of the above comments.

Comment: What's your basic field? $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 3):

Necessarily, $A$ is invertible and the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are also $\pm 1$. For every positive integer $k$, $rank((A+\epsilon I)^k)=rank(A^{-k}(A+\epsilon I)^k)=rank((A^{-1}+\epsilon I)^k)$ where $\epsilon \in\{\pm1\}$; we conclude using the Jordan test of similarity.